# How to access a deleted features attributes (before committing)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, stopiteration

I have a signal setup for a feature deletion event on a layer:

```
self.layer.featureDeleted.connect(self.feature_deleted)
```

When I try and grab an attribute from the deleted feature on the slot, a *StopIteration* error is thrown (i.e it cannot retrieve the feature).

I would have thought I  should still be able to retrieve attributes from a deleted feature before the changes to the layer are committed? Otherwise I don't see what use the fid parameter is.

```
def feature_deleted(self, fid):
    feature = self.layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(int(fid))).next()
    idx = self.layer.fieldNameIndex('my_attribute')
    print feature.attributes()[idx]
```

**How can I access the attributes of a deleted feature (before the changes to the layer are committed)?**

Comment: It seems that deleted features aren't stored anywhere ... except in the original version of your layer ... so ... maybe open it twice and then use the **deletedFeatureIds** returned by the **edit buffer** of the layer u're modifying ? I only found that attribute value changes or geometry changes  are stored ... not deleted features (only their featureIds are...)

Comment: @snaileater Copying the layer will be an expensive operation in my case. I will try and record the attributes of features as they are selected and compare them to those left once the changes are committed.

Comment: @Matt Maybe this posting on the mailing list will help: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2015-May/037823.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There would be two moments where you can still get features that are to be deleted:

1. When you delete them in an edit session but have not committed or saved changes (i.e., you could still rollback).

   ```
   layer = iface.activeLayer()
   idx = layer.fieldNameIndex( 'my_attribute' )
   def feature_deleted( fid ):
       feature = layer.dataProvider().getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( fid ) ).next()
       print feature.id(), feature.attributes()[idx]

   layer.featureDeleted.connect( feature_deleted )
   ```
2. Right before deleted features are committed (i.e., you've just clicked on the `Save Layer Edits` button or you've just called `layer.commitChanges()`).

   ```
   layer = iface.activeLayer()
   idx = layer.fieldNameIndex( 'my_attribute' )
   def features_deleted():
       if layer.editBuffer():
          ids = layer.editBuffer().deletedFeatureIds()
          for feature in layer.dataProvider().getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids( ids ) ):
              print feature.id(), feature.attributes()[idx]

   layer.beforeCommitChanges.connect( features_deleted )
   ```

Comment: This is a good solution but doesn't seem to work for postGis layers. It appears to me they handle the editing buffer fundamentally different. I get a stop iteration error even though the layer is still in edit mode. Any suggestions there?