# Accessing deleted feature attributes (before committing) QGIS 3.4?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

It's basically the same question as the one asked in the post: [How to access a deleted features attributes (before committing)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156431/how-to-access-a-deleted-features-attributes-before-committing), but the solution is not working in QGIS 3.4.

I do it the same way:

1. A Signal on featureDeleted

```
self.layer.featureDeleted.connect(self.feature_deleted)
```

2. A function to access attributes of the deleted feature:

```
def feature_deleted(self, fid):
    feature = self.layer.dataProvider().getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(fid)).next()
    print feature.attributes()
```

The problem is, this part:

```
self.layer.dataProvider().getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(fid))
```

is returning a QgsFeatureIterator which has no method .next() and I don't know how to access the feature from the Iterator otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just iterate using a `for` loop instead:

```py
def feature_deleted(self, fid):
    for feature in self.layer.dataProvider().getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(fid)):
        print(feature.attributes())
```

Comment: works! Great, thank you!

Comment: @Frings94 - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)